# change floating-point operation in x86 system to the one in armv8 system

Tags: floating-point, x86, stack, arm, inline-assembly

I read some inline assembly c code about floating-point operation. The code is as follows.

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("fninit);
//There are some other in line assembly here, I omit them because they have nothing to do with my question.
__asm__ __volatile__ ("fcomp %st");
```

These codes are run in x86 system. However, I want to change these code to the one that can run in armv8 system.

First, I want to know what is meaning of the above code. Second, I want to know how I can change the above code to make it run in armv8 system.

Comment: We are not a code translation service, nor here to teach you x86 and ARM assembler.

Comment: I just want to know the differences between the two systems. Just two instructions!

Comment: Have you googled the instructions in question? You have shown no evidence that you've tried to answer this question yourself.

Comment: The instructions in question is easy to find. However there are few documents about the corresponding operation in armv8.  Armv8 is a new computer architecture and the tutorial is lacking.

Comment: `FNINIT` initializes the x87 FPU. `FCOMP` compares the top of stack, `ST(0)`, with `ST(1)` and then pops the stack. What is being compared we can't tell because you didn't show the code. We also don't know what comparison operator is being implemented by this code since the code after the `FCOMP` is missing. Since comparison of floating-point operands is supported by HLLs, it is not clear for what purpose inline assembly is used here. What happens if you simply compare the operands at the HLL level?

Comment: You can't port individual instructions in isolation; sure you can cross-reference instruction listings and figure out that `fcomp` is a floating-point compare, so the rough A64 (I assume that of the 3 different instruction sets in ARMv8 you probably mean that one) equivalent would be (perhaps unsurprisingly) `fcmp`, but the ARM instruction takes two explicit arguments instead of the x87's implicit stack usage - what registers are you going to specify? Without considering the _intent_ of the code and restructuring the whole thing appropriately, you're still lost.

Comment: Incidentally, this doesn't have any specific relation to ARM either - replace "ARMv8" with "SSE2" in the question and pretty much the exact same considerations still stand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/index.html explains how the x87 FPU works, and is a useful reference when the Intel insn ref manuals don't tell you how the pieces fit together.  I'll add it to the x86 tag wiki.

You're on your own for ARM asm.

Are you sure you even need to write anything in asm, instead of just letting the compiler do it?  If you don't need to set the rounding mode, or set limited precision, or anything, just use C `double` or `float`.

Comment: I write a program that synthesizes a benchmark, so that is why I write something in asm. I can handle all the other operations. However, FP operations confused me a lot. Why the program need the FP stack to be initialized and restored.

Comment: Still, thank you for your help. This tutorial seems great.

Comment: @80247617aaa: "synthesizes a benchmark"?  No idea what that means.  Do you mean you wrote a program that *is* a synthetic benchmark?  Let the compiler take care of the FP details.  The ABI requires that the FP stack be empty when entering or returning from a function, except for holding an FP return value in 32bit x86.  It's not like a benchmark should be any different from any other program that uses floating point, as far as overflowing the FP stack or not.

Comment: I mean I write a program that can create a benchmark. I already have a program that can create a benchmark, but this program is designed for x86. I want to change the program to make it create the benchmark running on armv8. I am confused about the FP operations in the previous program(designed for x86) and I have no idea about whether I  need some FP operations in armv8 system.

Comment: @80247617aaa: you should probably figure out what performance characteristics you're interested in, so you can test what's relevant for you.  Otherwise just look at standard benchmark suites, like SPECint and SPECfp.  (although most of SPECint is not held in very high regard, due to small code-size, and current optimizing compilers seeing special-case optimizations in many of the benchmarks other than https://www.spec.org/cpu2006/Docs/403.gcc.html)